# manipulating an html table using foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I'm creating a table that generates new columns according to the dates being generated.

[image]

I able to create it but the problem is the table looks like this:

[image]

I think the problem is in my foreach but i can't pinpoint where the real problem is.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="3"><?php 
    $from = strtotime($_POST['from']);
    $to = strtotime($_POST['to']);
    if($list_timelist):
    do 
    {
        $current = date("Y-m-d", $from);

        $from = strtotime("+1 day", $from);
        $exist = 0;
        $date1 = "";
        $date2 ="";

    ?>          
        <?php 
        endforeach;
        if($exist==1)
        {
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($list->time_stamp));
            echo "
            <tr>    
                <th></th>
                <th colspan='3' class='date'>$date1</th>
            <tr>";
            echo "
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>UT</td>
                <td>LEAVE/ABSENT</td>
                <td>OT</td>";           
            echo "</tr>";               
        }
        else
        {
            $a=date("Y-m-d, D", strtotime($current));
            $b=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current));
            echo "
            <tr>
                <th colspan='3' class='date'>".$a."</th>                
            <tr>";
            echo"
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>UT</td>
                <td>LEAVE/ABSENT</td>
                <td>OT</td>             
            </tr>";                 
        }
    } while ($from <= $to); 
    else:
    endif;
    ?></th>
    <th colspan="3">Total</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Filed OT</th>
    <th rowspan="2">OT(previous cut-off)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Total OT for payment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>UT</td>
    <td>LEAVE/ABSENT</td>
    <td>OT</td>
    <td>UT<br>(hrs)</td>
    <td>LEAVE/ABSENT<br>(days)</td>
    <td>OT / Excess Time<br>(hrs)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>          

</table>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: open a discussion so i can help!

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi Hi! Thanks for your reply. What do you mean discussion?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64451/temporary-oki

Comment: have you join the room?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi Yes. I have joined the room.

Comment: Add my skype jewelnguyen8. I can help you.

Comment: @jewelnguyen8 Hi i dont have a skype account. can you create a chatroom here so i can join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn this block of code:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" border='1'>  
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <?php 
    $from = strtotime("2014-10-10");
    $to = strtotime("2014-10-12");

    //$interval = date_diff($from, $to);

    //$diff = $interval->format('%a');
    //echo $diff;
    do 
    {
        $current = date("Y-m-d", $from);

        $from = strtotime("+1 day", $from);
        $exist = 0;
        $date1 = "";
        $date2 ="";
            $a=date("Y-m-d, D", strtotime($current));
            $b=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current));
            echo "

                <th colspan='3' class='date'>".$a."</th>                
            ";
    }
    while ($from <= $to); 
    ?>
    <th colspan="3">Total</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Filed OT</th>
    <th rowspan="2">OT(previous cut-off)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Total OT for payment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <th></th>
  <?php
    $from = strtotime("2014-10-10");
    $to = strtotime("2014-10-12");
    do 
    {
        $current = date("Y-m-d", $from);

        $from = strtotime("+1 day", $from);
        $exist = 0;
        $date1 = "";
        $date2 ="";
            $a=date("Y-m-d, D", strtotime($current));
            $b=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current));
            echo"


                <td>UT</td>
                <td>LEAVE/ABSENT</td>
                <td>OT</td>             
            ";
    }
    while ($from <= $to);     
        ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

You have generated `<TR>` inside `<TH>` element. It causes the columns be nested.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The codes inside the <TH> element is there to duplicate the columns. The problem is the table is vertical and i need it to be nested horizontally.